# mediaelement.js - Can't override the element-style

Tags: css, overriding, mediaelement.js

I am having real problems trying to override the theme css. I have tried the old fall back of using !important but it doesn't work.

What is really annoying is that the audio default player size works but not the video.  It is driving me nuts do any of you have any idea how to solve it?

http://www.krissharmsworth.com/test/test-media/

Thanks in advance

Kriss :)

Comment: Which element, and with what css?

Comment: It is the width and height element...it is at 100% on the theme CSS and no matter what I do I can't change it. If I use the !important is changes the audio window as well as the video AND the video is still the same size.  :S

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem lies not in the div but in the object tag

strt changing the css from there using !important if required

```
<video id="wp_mep_2"   width="1024" height="576"  controls="controls" preload="none"  >




    <source src="http://www.krissharmsworth.com/test/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/Michael-victor.wmv" type="video/wmv" />


    <object width="1024" height="576" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="http://www.krissharmsworth.com/test/wp-content/plugins/media-element-html5-video-and-audio-player/mediaelement/flashmediaelement.swf">
        <param name="movie" value="http://www.krissharmsworth.com/test/wp-content/plugins/media-element-html5-video-and-audio-player/mediaelement/flashmediaelement.swf" />
        <param name="flashvars" value="controls=true&amp;file=" />          
    </object>       
</video>
```

These controls render at their default height so first change their css then the parent div . Wait ill give a screen shot in some minustes :)

Heres the screen shot i did by changing the styles of the media elements ie the video (silverlight or some thing) and then the above divs.

[image]

Comment: ok let me go and play and see what happens... :D

Comment: Ok just had a play and nothing happening...urgh can you give me a screen shot with the inspect element window open please?  oh and thanks so much for bearing with me on this...

Comment: ok no got it to work within the inspect element on Chrome BUT when I change the main theme css it is still reverting back to the original size embed, iframe, object, video {
max-width: 480px !important;
max-height: 370px !important
}

element.style {
width: 480px !important;
height: 370px !important;
}

Comment: try inlining it to the video element and see. Although not a good practice but see if it works or not :)

Comment: ok that term is new to me....how do you do that?  sorry know most things but get stuck when it gets a bit too technical... :D

Comment: <video id="wp_mep_2"  style=" width:400px !important; height:400px !important"  controls="controls" preload="none"  >

Comment: same way for every div above the video

Comment: oh right...thought that was what it meant but wasn't too sure...ok if I have to change it that will not be good for me as I have loads to upload...ahh well...thanks for all your help and think I might have to learn Javascript as well that might help... :D Kriss :)